# Is it possible to have 2 different services with the same application name?

Tags: spring, microservices, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

Let's say I have a service named "FooService" running in a docker container and a second service named "BarService" running in a second docker container. Both services register with Eureka (running in another docker container). Is it possible to have the same application name for both services? E.g. http://localhost/myservice/foo should call the FooService and http://localhost/myservice/bar should call the BarService. Development environment is Spring Boot and the services are implemented as Spring RestControllers. Just put "spring.application.name=myservice" in both bootstrap.properties files and then put @RequestMapping("${spring.application.name}") in the RestController will not work, of course. But is it somehow possible to register the services with a unique identifier and still call them with a common URL path?

Comment: Yes it is possible, process of routing and filtering requests to a microservice application using the Netflix Zuul edge service library.

Comment: Do you have more information or resources? Maybe an example?

Comment: https://spring.io/guides/gs/routing-and-filtering/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think this is a very common use case.  You develop version service-a, version 1, and you want to deploy service-a, version 2, (canary or blue/green)  You can deploy both versions, and register both versions with Eureka, and traffic will be sent to both versions. After you verify version 2, you can shut down version 1.